# Detect a tweet's writing direction

Tags: ios, utf-8, twitter, text-alignment

When using Twitter App for Mac, the app "knows" that English text should be displayed LTR and Arabic text RTL. Now, I am trying to pull and display tweets in my app, but I am not sure how to properly align the text. Some of the text I fetch is in Arabic, and some is in English. The text I fetch doesn't contain information about writing direction at all.

I realize that the `\u202b` UTF-8 character is used to make text aligned RTL, but it is missing from my twitter API response. I checked all the parameters, non seem to help with this issue. I even posted on their developers' discussion forums, but no reaction, at all.

For your reference, I am developing an iOS app and displaying the fetched text in a `UITextView`.

Comment: You could always test to see if the string contains, say, all Arabic, but at the end of the day if the string contains both Arabic and English (which so many do) then there is no easy way around it and normally it just aligns left.

Comment: @Sammaye Hence my astonishment at how twitter clients are able to pull of such feat. I am currently trying to sniff Twitter for Mac's packets... Maybe, just maybe...

Comment: There is one way, I notice when looking at my twitter feed (I don't use Mac or the apps for twitter so I am using my own knowledge of making sites in other languages): majority. If the majority of the string is Arabic then right align, cos the odd English word right aligned is fine (English is such a loose language) since a lot of names are written in English but that doesn't mean the string should be aligned LTR. I think that could work.

Comment: My only hint up till now is some text align option called 'Natural Align', which uses an algorithm to appropriately align the text